# How do you add a custom loading animation on Xcode? Should Xcode be used or an animation software?

Tags: xcode, animation

I would like to add a short animation of an envelope opening and an object coming out while the app is being launched and loading.

I am not sure for something like this, I should use Xcode the way it is done [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/102590/how-to-create-a-complex-loading-animation-in-swift) or whether I should create an animation on another software and load the finished file on xcode.

I'm new to creating any kind of animation and I apologize if this is a very basic newb question.

Comment: Have you heard of Core Animator? It's not cheap but it's really good; it generates swift source code in a class that you can just copy paste into your project. Animations are created in Core Animator by using a UI--no coding needed!

Comment: @Dopapp that sounds great! Thank you very much!